# Why am I getting ORA-00900 Invalid SQL statement when trying to create a directory object with execute immediate?

Tags: oracle, ddl, execute-immediate

I see many examples of this being possible in Oracle. It's just not working for me. Oracle 11. I am getting this error on line 15. Thank you all!

```
declare 
v_path nvarchar2(256);
v_object_exists number;
begin
    -- Use the directory Oracle DB provide for tracing.
    select VALUE into v_path from V$DIAG_INFO where NAME = 'Diag Trace';
    --dbms_output.put_line(v_path);

    -- Set up new directory!
    select count(*) into v_object_exists from all_objects where object_name = 'DIAG_TRACE' and object_type = 'DIRECTORY';
    if v_object_exists > 0 then 
        execute immediate 'DROP DIRECTORY DIAG_TRACE'; 
    end if;
    dbms_output.put_line('CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY DIAG_TRACE AS ''' || v_path || '''');
    execute immediate 'CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY DIAG_TRACE AS ''' || v_path || '''';

end;
```

Comment: A permissions problem with the filesystem directory? Can you execute it directly from your interface (sqldeveloper, sqlplus, sqlci)?

Comment: @JeffHolt - a DROP DIRECTORY never touches the actual OS file system.  The directory being dropped is just an object within the database ... an alias for a directory on the OS file system.

Comment: @EdStevens True, but the OP said line 15 which is the create, not the drop.

Comment: @JeffHolt - that applies to the create too. The OS side isn't evaluated until you try to use the directory (i.e. read/write) - which can be a bit confusing. The path isn't even validated when it's created.

Comment: Yes, I can run the statement just fine if I run it manually.

Comment: @JeffHolt - same applies to CREATE.  It's just creating an object within the database that is nothing but an alias for an OS directory.  The formatting limitations of comments here prevent posting a proof case, but it's easy enough.  Just try to create a directory object referencing a non-existent OS directory. (Edit - I see Alex Poole beat me to the same observation).

Comment: Solution was use varchar2 instead of nvarchar2. Execute immediate didn't like nvarchar2. TY all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug; though not one listed on the ORA-00900 reference note on MoS.

It doesn't like the path variable being concatenated in as part of the `execute immediate`. This fails:

```
v_path := '/some/path';
execute immediate 'CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY DIAG_TRACE AS ''' || v_path || '''';
```

but this is OK, even though the final statement is the same:

```
execute immediate 'CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY DIAG_TRACE AS ''/some/path''';
```

After some searching, it may be something to do with bug 7036176: "CONCATENATED DYNAMIC OBJECT NAME RAISES ORA-00900 IN 10G & 11G". It's not exactly the same but close. You'll need to look on My Oracle Support for further info, though there isn't much.

You can work around it with a variable:

```
declare
v_stmt varchar2(256);
v_path nvarchar2(256);
v_object_exists number;
begin
    -- Use the directory Oracle DB provide for tracing.
    select VALUE into v_path from V$DIAG_INFO where NAME = 'Diag Trace';
    --dbms_output.put_line(v_path);
    -- Set up new directory!
    select count(*) into v_object_exists from all_objects where object_name = 'DIAG_TRACE' and object_type = 'DIRECTORY';
    if v_object_exists > 0 then
        execute immediate 'DROP DIRECTORY DIAG_TRACE';
    end if;
    v_stmt := 'CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY DIAG_TRACE AS ''' || v_path || '''';
    dbms_output.put_line(v_stmt);
    execute immediate v_stmt;
end;
/
```

Which saves repeating the string to print it, though you might only have done that because of this issue.

Not sure why you're dropping first with `or replace`, incidentally.

Comment: This is great! I tried this but made my v_stmt as a nvarchar2. It turns out, execute immediate doesn't like that! I change my original script variables to varchar2 and it works! Thank you!

Comment: Re: Or Replace and Drop: That's what Toad auto generates for some reason. I used the default script as my baseline.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer putting a command into a variable, display it (for verification) and then execute it:

```
SQL> declare
  2  v_path nvarchar2(256);
  3  v_object_exists number;
  4  l_str varchar2(200);
  5  begin
  6      -- Use the directory Oracle DB provide for tracing.
  7      select VALUE into v_path from V$DIAG_INFO where NAME = 'Diag Trace';
  8      --dbms_output.put_line(v_path);
  9
 10      -- Set up new directory!
 11      select count(*) into v_object_exists from all_objects where object_name = 'DIAG_TRACE' and object_type = 'DIRECTORY';
 12      if v_object_exists > 0 then
 13          execute immediate 'DROP DIRECTORY DIAG_TRACE';
 14      end if;
 15      l_str := 'CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY DIAG_TRACE AS ' || chr(39) || v_path ||chr(39);
 16      dbms_output.put_line(l_str);
 17      execute immediate l_str;
 18  end;
 19  /
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY DIAG_TRACE AS
'C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\diag\rdbms\xe\xe\trace'

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Certainly, you have to run it as a privileged user (such as SYS).